# Magento Page creation without hitting URL and save that Page in Varnish Cache

Tags: magento-2.1, varnish

Can a Magento 2.x Page be created without hitting URL(I mean without CURL Request) and save that Page in Varnish Cache? If possible then the Cache Warming can be faster. Now it takes a lot of time.

Comment: No.. It is not. Any way one time hitting db is necessary to create cache. We created two level cache FPC in redis and varnish

Comment: But Site Warming takes time for FPC. We want to process 60k pages in 60 minutes at most for magento 2 pages. that's why searching something clever.